# Convert code to open Firefox instead of Internet Explorer

Tags: autoit

How do I change Internet Explorer to Firefox?

```
#include <IE.au3>
    Func _CreateIE()
        If Not IsObj($oIE) Or Not ProcessExists("iexplore.exe") Then
            $oIE = _IECreate($sURL, 0)
        EndIf
    EndFunc   ;==>_CreateIE
```

Comment: You'll need the FF.au3 UDF file: https://www.autoitscript.com/forum/topic/167661-ffau3-v0601b-15/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To just open the Firefox browser the following native AutoIt code suffices:

```
local $url="www.google.com"
$off=Run(@ProgramFilesDir & "\Mozilla Firefox\firefox.exe " & $url, "", @SW_MAXIMIZE)
```

For full support you'll need the [user defined function](https://www.autoitscript.com/wiki/User_Defined_Functions) [**FF.au3**](https://www.autoitscript.com/forum/topic/95595-ffau3-v0601b-10/), which in turn requires the add-on [**mozrepl**](https://github.com/bard/mozrepl/wiki).

Don't forget to start MozRepl.
FF-menu: Extras/Menu or check there "Activate on startup".

Then you can do:

```
#Include <FF.au3>
_FFStart([$sURL = "about:blank"[, $sProfile = "default"[, $iMode = 1[, $bHide = False[, $IP = "127.0.0.1"[, $iPort = 4242]]]]]])
```

References:
http://english.documentation.ff-au3.thorsten-willert.de
https://www.autoitscript.com/wiki/User_Defined_Functions
https://www.autoitscript.com/forum/topic/95595-ffau3-v0601b-10/
https://github.com/bard/mozrepl/wiki